# QLIK Sense (sum with the condition)

Tags: sum, distinct, qliksense

I need to show the sum of the columns of only those values when the 3 columns combined are unique.
Right now my expression looks like this: Num(Sum([myColumn]) , '# ##0,00')
I need to add a condition similar to (where Dictinct col1, col2, col3).
Can you tell me how to do it?

I tried to write like this:
Num(Sum(distinct {[col1] + [col2] + [col3]} [mycolumn]), '# ##0.00')
, but it didn't help

id|     col1|     col2|     col3|     mycolumn|

1|     0001|      810|      yes|        10.00|

2|     0001|      810|      yes|        10.00|

3|     0001|      840|       no|        25.11|

4|     0001|      840|      yes|       |25.11|

5|     0001|      392|      yes|        15.01|

6|     0001|      756|      yes|        15.01|

```
                        total        90,24
```

col1, col2, and col3 in records with id1 and id2 are equal, so only one of them goes into the sum. In records id3 and id4 col3 are different, so two columns add up.  In records id5 and id6 the col2 column is different, so they add up too.
Total: 10.00 + 25.11 + 25.11 + 15.01 + 15.01

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add example of your data and expected output.

Comment: added to the question description